# unix: delete everything before a sequence of bytes

Tags: regex, sed, binary

I have binary files and I want to delete everything before (and including) a certain sequence of bytes (five times '7e'). For example I have a file test:

```
hexdump test
0000000 000a 4ffa 0a0d 7e7e 7e7e 837e 646f 0110
0000010 8318 dac3                              
0000014
```

The result should be:

```
hexdump test1
0000000 6f83 1064 1801 c383 00da               
0000009
```

I tried it with `cat test | sed 's/.*~~~~~//'` however, it only deleted the '~~~~~' and keeps the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed with binary files is not going to end well, since it does some locale- and encoding-dependent things and generally expects to work on text files. There is another utility, `bbe` (binary block editor), that is better suited to this task. With it, you can do this:

```
bbe -b ':/~~~~~/' -e 'D 1' test
```

This states that blocks are units that end with `~~~~~` and instructs `bbe` to delete the first of them (`D 1`).

The problem you run into with sed, discounting encoding snafu, is that sed works line by line.  If you are hell-bent on doing it with sed (in which case you can expect random failures), this *might* work on some platforms:

```
sed '1,/~~~~~/ { /~~~~~/!d; s/^.*~~~~~// }' test
```

This will, in the pattern range `1,/~~~~~/` (from the first line to the first that contains `~~~~~`) delete lines that do not contain `~~~~~` and remove the part up to `~~~~~` from the line that eventually does. This is more brittle than the `bbe` approach in more ways than one; apart from the encoding snafu, it will break if `~~~~~` appears twice between two `0a` (newline) bytes. **If this is for serious use, go with `bbe`**.